# Multi-part gzip file random access (in Java)

Tags: compression, gzip, multipart, random-access

This may fall in the realm of "not really feasible" or "not really worth the effort" but here goes.

I'm trying to randomly access records stored inside a multi-part gzip file. Specifically, the files I'm interested in are compressed [Heretrix](http://crawler.archive.org/) Arc files. (In case you aren't familiar with multi-part gzip files, the gzip spec allows multiple gzip streams to be concatenated in a single gzip file. They do not share any dictionary information, it is simple binary appending.)

I'm thinking it should be possible to do this by seeking to a certain offset within the file, then scan for the gzip magic header bytes (i.e. 0x1f8b, as per the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt)), and attempt to read the gzip stream from the following bytes. The problem with this approach is that those same bytes can appear inside the actual data as well, so seeking for those bytes can lead to an invalid position to start reading a gzip stream from. Is there a better way to handle random access, given that the record offsets aren't known a priori?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of GZIP, as you have realized, is not friendly to random access.

You can do as you describe, and then if you run into an error in the decompressor, conclude that the signature you found was actually compressed data.
If you finish decompressing, then it's easy to verify the validity of the stream just decompressed, via the CRC32.

If the files are not so big, you might consider just de-compressing all of the entries in series, and retaining the offsets of the signatures so as to build a directory.  As you decompress, dump the bytes to a bit bucket. At that point you will have generated a directory, and you can then support random access based on filename, date, or other metadata.

This will be reasonably fast for files below 100k.  Just as a guess, if you had 10 files of around 100k each, it would probably be done in 2s on a modern CPU.  This is what I mean by "pretty fast".  But only you know the perf requirements of your application .

Do you have a GZipInputStream class? If so you are half-way there.

Answer (score 3):

The **BGZF** file format, compatible with GZIP was developped by the biologists.

> (...) The advantage of
>   BGZF over conventional gzip is that
>   BGZF allows for seeking without having
>   to scan through the entire file up to
>   the position being sought.

In http://picard.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/picard/trunk/src/java/net/sf/samtools/util/ , have a look at BlockCompressedOutputStream and BlockCompressedInputStream.java